# useState typescript predefined string error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

how to set predefined string (enum) in react's useState? I tried:

```
const [color, setColor] =
    React.useState<"red | blue">("blue");
```

but I got error of

```
Argument of type '"blue"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"red | blue" | (() => "red | blue")'.ts(2345)
```

demo https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-jmj6c?file=/src/App.tsx:85-148

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two double quotations in your type.

Instead of

```
"red | blue"
```

it should be

```
"red" | "blue"
```

Comment: @Jennifer Alexis, check this out !!

Answer (score 0):

`const [color, setColor] = React.useState<"red" | "blue">("blue");`

or:

```
type Color = "red" | "blue";  
const [color, setColor] = React.useState<Color>("blue");
```